# Calling stored procedure using spring data jpa where SP is operating on multiple tables and returning a result set

Tags: java, spring, jpa, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

How to call a stored procedure using spring data jpa where the SP is operating on multiple tables and returning a result set of  multiple new columns which is formed based on some business logic & coming from multiple tables.

I referred the existing Stackoverflow posts. but all of them are very simple & they deal with only one table.

my requirement is a bit bit complex.
Do I need to write a new Entity class based on the resultset ?
As per the traditional mindset I would assume there should be some Entity class with whom I have to write the JPA Repository class & do the CRUD operations. 
But here is the concern, I am not sure what will be the entity class which should be mapped to the JPA repository as the Stored Procedure deals with multiple entity classes & produces a result set with new columns from multiple tables after doing some business validations.